# How to appear option when type number in input text javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm sorry but I'm new in javascript, so I want to ask something. So I want to suddenly appear an option when I type the num in input text. So for example, if I type 2 in the input text, there will be 2 option that appear.

```
    <input type="num" name="member" id="member" value="">
```

Comment: 2 options where? I mean where you want it to appear?

Comment: Of course in the bottom of input num, it suddenly appear without submit anything.

Comment: what sort of options? select element options?

Comment: Look for `document.createElement` and `.appendChild`

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao Yes, just element option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may you point in the right direction:

```js
function addOptions() {
  // "Reset" the div to prevent unwanted behavior
  document.getElementById('selects').innerHTML = "";

  // Get the value of your input field
  var inputValue = document.getElementById('member').value;

  // A loop to append as many selects as required (e. g. if inputValue is 2, 2 selects will appear
  for (var i = 0; i < inputValue; i++) {
    var select = document.createElement('select'); // Create the select
    var option = document.createElement('option'); // Create the option for the select
    option.innerText = "Example"; // Set a text for the option

    select.appendChild(option); // Append the option to the select
    document.getElementById('selects').appendChild(select); // Append the select to the body
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onkeyup="addOptions()" name="member" id="member" value="">
<div id="selects"></div>
```

**Note related to my edit:**

As a comment stated on my answer, there would be unwanted behavior if the user changes the inputs value. E. g. the user types in 2, but changes it to 4. After that, the user will have 6 selects when they only want to have 4.

Therefore, I added `document.getElementById('selects').innerHTML = "";` to the script in order to prevent that. For that, I also changed the script to append the selects to a div, not directly to the body.

Comment: This is good but it's buggy, because if you put for example 2 in input and then 4 you will get 6 selects which is not what OP wanted

Comment: Yet OP still accepted this as the best answer. Thing is, he asked a very broad question that was unclear. And didn't show any of his own code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it with javascript. Also, I would assume you need to clear options before next change.

```js
function createOptions(iterations){
  var select = document.getElementById("optmem"); //assuming select will be already present
  removeOptions(select); //clear options
  for(var i=0;i!= iterations;i++){
    //loop through each iterations
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Text "+i;
    option.value = "myvalue "+i;
    select.appendChild(option); //append it to select
  }
}

function removeOptions(selectbox)
{
    var i;
    for(i = selectbox.options.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        selectbox.remove(i);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="num" name="member" id="member" onchange="createOptions(this.value)" value=""/>
<select id="optmem">

</select>
```